# Split ifstream in n streams?

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream, istream, seekg

i have problems with an ifstream. I want to split the ifstream in n parts.

For example n = 3:

1. Ifstream includes first 1/3 of the file.
2. Ifstream includes second 1/3 of the file.
3. Ifstream includes third 1/3 of the file.

```
    std::ifstream in("test.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> v1;
    std::vector<std::string> v2;
    std::vector<std::string> v3;

    //first 1/3 of file
    read(in, v1);
    //second 1/3 of file
    read(in, v2);
    //third 1/3 of file
    read(in, v3);

    read(in, v){

         std::string line {""};
         while(getline(in, line)){
              v.pushback(line);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, there are many ways. Do you want 3 ifstreams returned, do you just want to do 3 reads? More detail required.

Comment: i want to do 3 reads from certain points in the stream

Comment: So there are methods seekg() and tellg(), that can help you to find out the size of the file in bytes, then go back and read and test if you have reached 1/3 or 2/3. They are not going to be exact, as the lines may not be exactly splitting the file. If you want to split it by number of lines that can only be done by reading the whole file into a vector of lines and then splitting that vector.

Comment: The problem is i can not operate inside of read() or change the arguments. Is there a way to just pass 2/3 of ifstream?

Comment: Then create three ifstreams. Get the size of the file. Seek the second ifstream to 1/3rd of the file and the third ifstream to 2/3rd. And yes, you'll have to create 3 separate ifstreams since an ifstream can have only a single state and also cannot be copied.

Comment: If i seek to 1/3 of the stream, ifstream includes the 2/3 and the 3/3 but i just want to have the 2/3. Because i can not change the eof()

Comment: Ok, now we start to understand your problem. You will need to show us the exact signature of the read function you cannot change. It is possible to make your own streambuf implementation behind istream, and that could provide the functionality to kick eof early.

Comment: Ok i don't know what you mean with signature but i can explain the read function more. My programm is a reader for fasta files. Fasta entries are placed in a struct fasta_t which includes a vector. protoype of read: void read (fasta_t & fasta, std::istream & in); it reads the istream line by line and stores the data in fasta_t. My proramm has a split function where the outputfiles i create should be split in n files. So i want to split the istream in n parts read it line by line and store the data in fasta_t then write it to outputfile 1 and so on.

Comment: You can read and push all lines in a `std::vector<std::string>` and then split the vector in n parts

Answer (score 1):

You can read and push all lines in a vector and then split the vector in 3 part, for example:

```
std::string s;
while(!in.eof() && getline(in, s)) v1.push_back(s);
int size = v1.size(), itv2 = 0, itv3 = 0, chunk = v1.size()/3;
for(unsigned i = size-1; i >= size/3; --i, v1.pop_back()) 
    (i > chunk*2)? v3[chunk-itv3++] = v1[i] : v2[chunk-itv2++] = v1[i];
```

And well now if you wanna do this for n partitions you can do something like that:

```
//n must be defined before use
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vChunks(n+1);
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string s;
while(!in.eof() && getline(in, s)) v.push_back(s);
int size = v.size(), chunk = v.size()/n, r = v.size()%n;
vChunks[n].resize(r);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    vChunks[i].resize(chunk);
for(int i = v.size()-1, it =1; it <= r; it++, --i, v.pop_back())
    vChunks[n][r-it] = v[i];
for(int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; --i, v.pop_back())
    vChunks[(i%chunk == 0)? (i-1)/chunk : i/chunk][i%chunk] = v[i];
```

Where `vChunks` the first n partitions have the number of lines between n dimensions and in n + 1 has dimension the rest of the last lines if it is not divisible by n the total number of lines

Answer (score 1):

@Mandy007 showed you a simple way to do it, by pre-reading all the content into memory.

The "clean" way to do it would be to define a `streambuf`-derived class that delegates read requests through to the underlying `istream` but manipulates the seek position and end-of-file indication to make it look like the region of the file is a complete stream.

This is how customization works in the iostream library... the stream classes themselves are not polymorphic, all behavior comes from the `streambuf` instance.